# Can I use Material-UI in an email template?

Tags: reactjs, email, material-ui

I'm attempting to convert the emails in my project to use React as templating engine. It works well, but I am also trying to reuse theming from our main app by adding Material-UI to the mix, that's when everything breaks. I made sure to place all the styled in the head of the email, use classes, it doesn't need to fetch any external stylesheets. Yet Gmail just ignores all my styling. I assume it's because it doesn't like something particular, but I know they're pretty strict and generally tend to ignore things when they don't like something.

My question then is, has someone tried using Material-UI in emails and overcome those challenges? Or maybe you just know that it won't work and I should abandon hope? All help is appreciated :)

Comment: It will be very hard to simply re-use any of material-ui styles as many selectors will not be supported by a great number of email clients.

Comment: Unfortunately that's true. I found though that the email displays perfectly in Thunderbird, but Gmail blocks the styling and instead does plain text only (which works surprisingly well with this approach), so all hope might not be lost

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment by @trixn, it's ends up being too complicated to try and use the original lib. Not so much the selectors, but some even modern email clients don't support rather normal properties like `line-height`. I could try and extract only the basic styles for the elements that I use, but that leaves no guarantee that they'll still work. We ended up just copy pasting the styles that are relevant to us.

CONCLUSION: no, it is not possible to use pure Material-UI to craft emails.